# std::string class find function not returning expected results. I may be using it incorrectly

Tags: c++

Using the find method of the string class and I'm not getting the correct results in my query. Here is my code

```
int main()
{
    string phoneData;
    string name;
    string phoneNumbers[51];
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("phonebook");
    int i = 0;
    while (getline(inputFile, phoneData))
    {
        phoneNumbers[i] = phoneData;
        i++;
    }
    cout << "Enter a name or partial name to search for: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << endl << "Here are the results of the search: " << endl;

    for(int i =0;i<50;i++)
    {
        if (name.find(phoneNumbers[i]) == 0)
            cout << phoneNumbers[i] << endl;
    }
    inputFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to finish your ques

Comment: I would expect that you need to use `if(phoneNumbers[i].find(name) != std::string::npos)` instead of `name.find(phoneNumbers[i]) == 0`

Comment: Any reference would tell you what it returns.

Comment: Hahaha, just somebody. Yeah I'm not sure what happened there but I edited it. Must have been distracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you aren't using it correctly. string::find() returns the beginning position when it finds a match, or string::npos if it doesn't find a match. you also have the search backwards. you're looking for 'name' inside 'phoneNumbers[i], not the other way around. your check inside the loop should look like this:

```
if (phoneNumbers[i].find(name) != string::npos)
    cout << phoneNumbers[i] << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had a hard time understanding the syntax of this method but now I understand. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry I was busy with school work. It's finals week! But I didn't forget, I always come back and do the right things. Thanks again for clearing this up.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (name.find(phoneNumbers[i]) == 0)
```

to

```
if (phoneNumbers[i].find(name) != std::string::npos)
```

The former is trying to locate phoneNumbers[i] within name.  The second (which I believe is what you intended) is searching for name within phoneNumbers[i]. Second, the failure return for `std::string::find` is `std::string::npos` not zero.